# github unavailable on my mac

Tags: networking, macos

I've tried hitting [GitHub](https://github.com/%20GitHub) on my mac running mac os x Sierra (10.12.6) using Google Chrome.

But when I do I get an error:

```
This site can’t be reached
github.com took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
ReloadHIDE DETAILS
```

I've checked my advanced network settings. And I don't have any proxies setup at all. My local mac firewall is off.

I've also tried visiting GitHub under chrome Incognito. And I get the same result there. This also happens under Safari and Firefox.

I know that github is up from checking [Down For Everyone or Just Me](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/). It just doesn't work from my mac.

It does the same thing for me under Firefox and Firefox Private. Safari and Safari private. None of that works.

Any help or suggestions on how to get this working would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try it from other devices on the same network as your Mac? Did you try rebooting your NAT gateway?

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but the address you placed into the link within your question is odd (It is http://github.com/%20GitHub)

Comment: Also, can you ping github.com, and can you return an IP address if you do a DNS lookup?

Comment: Thanks. When I fire up my work laptop (it's using windows 10), I can pull up the github site with no problem. 

I notice that I can't ping it from either machine tho. I think it may be that they have ICMP responses turned off. 

If I do an nslookup, this is what I get back: `Server:  192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: github.com
Address: 192.30.253.112
Name: github.com
Address: 192.30.253.1131` 

I notice it's using my router as the DNS server.

Comment: Since this is Github, try [testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/) directly with increased verbosity (`-vvv`). Add in the trace for that try as additional debug information here if it does not help.

Comment: Do you have any special settings in your /etc/hosts file for github.com?

Comment: Yes thank you. That was it. I had an entry for github.com in my /etc/hosts file. Thanks for the tip! github.com works fine now on my mac.